# Accessing methods in higher class in Java

Tags: java

### Context

I'm making a 2D game in Java.

I have this Java scheme :

```
| Map | ---- | BlockGrid | ---- | Block |
```

where Map, BlockGrid and Block are Java classes.

Here, the **Map class** has a **BlockGrid attribute** and the **BlockGrid class** has a **Block[ ][ ] attribute** storing all the blocks in the grid.

### My goal

I want to be able to access methods in my Map instance from my Block class.
For example, I want to call `spawnEntity(..)` on the Map instance to spawn an Arrow or something.

### Solutions ?

I thought about making `spawnEntity(..)` **static** but I know it is not a good practice since in order to spawn an entity, the Map need to be instanciated.

I also thought about passing my **Map instance as parameter in each constructor**. That way, BlockGrid and Block would have access to the instance and would be able to call methods.

### My question

What is the best practice for this case ?
Thank you.

Comment: passing Map instance as parameter in each constructor should be the best practice

Comment: No. But I have used that practice before and it's work fine.

Comment: Passing a reference should work in simple cases. If you want to go further, you can consider implementing [the observer pattern](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/observer).

Comment: People have used gotos and probably they also thought, that goto worked fine.

Comment: Do you want the **single best practice** or would viable practices do?

Comment: I would avoid passing a reference to a concrete class (`Map` in this case) as it would violate Dependency Inversion Principle. I would rather pass an abstraction/interface to `BlockGrid` in case this needs to be changed later.

Ideally, to fully adhere to DIP I would completely decouple/extract `spawnEntity` logic from `Map` and into its own class and pass it as a constructor parameter instead using either DI/factory pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a good practice is to have [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) of unrelated components. This means that if you choose to make the methods of your `Map` class available to the `Block` class by passing down references you should consider doing that via an interface (see Omars answer). This way you can initialize your `Block`s with objects of other classes instead of just `Map` instances if you later choose to do so.

But the second thing you should ask yourself if it really is a `Block`s responsibility to be able to spawn entities? I would say *no* because a `Block` is probably just a representation of a location plus some structure (although I don't know the semantics of your program). By choosing a different way to structure your programm you avoid introducing [circular dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) (`Map` depends on `Block`, `Block` depends on `Map`) which are usually considered a really bad thing (among other things, because you get a *high coupling* of your components) and follow the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (because `Block`s are not responsible any longer for spawning entities).

In my opinion, you shouldn't allow accessing `Map`s from `Block`s but instead make it `Map` responsibility to spawn entities. One way of doing it would be:

```
public final class Map {
    private final BlockGrid blockGrid;

    public Map(BlockGrid grid) {this.blockGrid = grid;}

    public void spawnEntityAt(int x, int y) {
        Block block = this.blockGrid.getBlockAt(x, y);
        // spawn the entity using information from 'block'

    }
}

final class BlockGrid {
    private final Block[][] grid;

    public BlockGrid(Block[][] grid) { this.grid = grid; }

    public Block getBlockAt(int x, int y) {
        return this.grid[x][y];
    }
}

final class Block {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface:

```
interface EntitySpawner {
    void spawnEntity(...);
}
```

Make your `Map` class implement this interface, then make `BlockGrid` accept `EntitySpawner` as an argument.

```
class Map implements EntitySpawner {

    private final BlockGrid grid = new BlockGrid(this);

    @Override
    public void spawnEntity(..) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```